# Yii2 Trying to get property 'chnmem_stid' of non-object

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2 Advanced and I'm getting this error

```
Trying to get property 'chnmem_stid' of non-object
```

The error is in this function in $isMember->chnmem_stid;

```
public function actionChannel($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModelUID($id);
    $isMember = AxChnPermission::ChnMember($model->channel_id);

    $memberStt = array(1,2,3);

    if (in_array($isMember->chnmem_stid, $memberStt))
    {
        $dataProviderPost = AxChannelProvider::ContentProviderMember ($model->channel_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $dataProviderPost = AxChannelProvider::ContentProviderGuest ($model->channel_id);
    }

    return $this->render('/channel/_viewPost', [
        'model' => $this->findModelUID($id),
        'isMember' => $isMember,
        'dataProviderPost' => $dataProviderPost,
    ]);
}
```

the function AxChnPermission::ChnMember($model->channel_id); is

```
public static function ChnMember($chn_id)
{
    $member = ChnMember::findOne(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, 'channel_id' => $chn_id]);
    return $member;
}
```

so the function I want to return only one result, The "chnmem_stid" is set to hasOne in model

```
    /**
 * This is the model class for table "chnmember".
 *
 * @property string $member_note
 * @property int $user_id
 * @property int $channel_id
 * @property int $channel_admin
 * @property int $chnmem_stid
 * @property string $chnmem_date
 * @property int $dsh_statut
 *
 * @property Channel $channel
 * @property User $user
 * @property ChnmemberStatut $chnmemSt
 * @property Channel $channelAdmin
 */
  /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */




public function getChnmemSt()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ChnmemberStatut::className(), ['chnmem_stid' => 'chnmem_stid']);
}
```

The error appears if return of this function is NULL

```
public static function ChnMember($chn_id)
{
    $member = ChnMember::findOne(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, 'channel_id' => $chn_id]);
    return $member;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `AxChnPermission::ChnMember()` may return `null` (if requested record does not exist). And this is probably the case, since error message says that `$isMember` is not object. You need to make additional check for this case:

```
$isMember = AxChnPermission::ChnMember($model->channel_id);
if ($isMember === null) {
    // throw exception?
}
```